# How to insert data into MySQL database from the form created in WordPress site

Tags: database, mysql

How can I insert the data entered into the form in WordPress site to the MySQL database? I have created a form in the site. I am able to run PHP codes using snippets but I don't know how to update the database table from the values entered into the form in the WordPress site.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, i use [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) and it's third party extension for storing values in database i.e.: https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-cfdb7/.

Or, if you want to create a custom form and store the value in database you can Create a Custom Post Type and use [wp_insert_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) function to insert your respective values.

Comment: I wanted to save the values in the form to my user-defined table in db. How can I do that?